# Storm Starter 1.2.2 example does not run (NimbusLeaderNotFoundException)

Tags: apache-storm

This is a default configuration just as it was in the example without any changes.  I am just trying to get the basic example to work.

I am trying to run the examples in Storm 1.2.2.  I built the storm-starter project and trying to execute with the following command line:

```
storm jar target/storm-starter-1.2.2.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -local
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
apara:storm-starter aparansky$ storm jar target/storm-starter-1.2.2.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -local
Running: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2 -Dstorm.log.dir=/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/*:/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/lib/*:/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/extlib/*:target/storm-starter-1.2.2.jar:/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/conf:/Users/aparansky/tools/apache-storm-1.2.2/bin -Dstorm.jar=target/storm-starter-1.2.2.jar -Dstorm.dependency.jars= -Dstorm.dependency.artifacts={} org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -local
564  [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.Utils - STORM-VERSION new 1.2.2 old null
589  [main] INFO  o.a.s.StormSubmitter - Generated ZooKeeper secret payload for MD5-digest: -9005967827641819579:-6463032051328979624
683  [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - WILL SLEEP FOR 2001ms (NOT MAX)
2690 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - WILL SLEEP FOR 2002ms (NOT MAX)
4692 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - WILL SLEEP FOR 2007ms (NOT MAX)
6702 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - WILL SLEEP FOR 2009ms (NOT MAX)
8715 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - WILL SLEEP FOR 2024ms (NOT MAX)
10740 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:112) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:73) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:136) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:92) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:66) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:58) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.getListOfKeysFromBlobStore(StormSubmitter.java:595) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.validateConfs(StormSubmitter.java:561) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:207) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:387) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:423) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:404) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology.main(ExclamationTopology.java:76) [storm-starter-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:64) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:56) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:104) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:105) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:53) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:104) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:105) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:53) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:104) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:66)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:58)
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.getListOfKeysFromBlobStore(StormSubmitter.java:595)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.validateConfs(StormSubmitter.java:561)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:207)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:387)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:423)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology.main(ExclamationTopology.java:76)
```

I am running with Java 1.8.0_65-b17:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am just trying to run in local mode on MAC OSX 10.13.5.  I could have sworn this was working before but stopped working after a recent OS update.  I have tried disabling Firewall and that did not help either.

Any ideas what I can check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems that any parameters passed into the program will try to startup in a clustered and not stand alone mode.  So, using `-local` at the end of the command line was causing issues.